# Joomla develop new Template on Live Site

Tags: templates, joomla

I have to work on a Joomla 2.5 Template. Is there a way to work on a template even the site is Online but only I can see the changes?

I thought that I do something with a get var &switch=true
and then ask for this var in my template and output a new css file. But as I also have to change something the dom this way is not working.

Is there something like -> when I am logged in at the Backend as admin, Joomla takes the new Template and all other visitors see the normal life Template?

Kind regards,

tbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add a parameter to your url

```
http://example.com/joomla/index.php?template=beez5
```